# How to call a variable outside the for loop?

Tags: javascript, canvas, scope

I think this is a special case. Since I have the update function outside the current function, I have to access the variable (object) sinEnemy in the update.
How can I do that when I need the i and j? This is not the complete code as you can see, since it takes hundreds or lines. This is just the for loop. (x2).
So, all I need is accessing sinEnemy in the update function.

```
for(i = 0; i < levelRows; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < levelCols; j++){
            if(level[i][j] == 3){
                // sinEnemy object
                var sinEnemy = {
                    x: j * tileSize,
                    y: i * tileSize,
                    width: tileSize,
                    height: tileSize
                }
                // Change color to blue
                ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

                if(keys[84]){
                    sinEnemy.x += 15;
                }
                    // Draw sinEnemy
                    ctx.fillRect(sinEnemy.x, sinEnemy.y, tileSize, tileSize);

                // Collide with sinEnemy
                rectCollision(player,sinEnemy);

                // var x = enemies1[i].x + Math.sin(enemies1[i].speed) * offset;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems like the problem is a little more complex than that. You probably want to *set up* all IxJ sinEnemys, as a two-dimensional array somewhere else, so that their x and y isn't always an exact number on every redraw of the canvas. That will require its own double-for loop, but that'll only run once. Then, inside *this* for loop, just retrieve a sinEnemy by the two indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable, in other words declare `sinEnemy` outside of your function.

Comment: I would reply with the same comment as the other guy above.

Comment: @GSquadron If you can't use a global variable then you should pass all the necessary information to your update function as parameters

Answer (score 0):

What both the previous answers mean but hasn't been clear about is this:

Outside the for-loops, declare your sinEnemy

`var sinEnemy = new Array();`

Then, inside your for-loops you'll push a new sinEnemy into your array of enemies.

```
 sinEnemy[sinEnemy.length] = {
    x: j * tileSize,
    y: i * tileSize,
    width: tileSize,
    height: tileSize
}
```